# Is there any quality difference between MurmurHash32 and static_cast<MurmurHash32>(MurmurHash128)?

Tags: c, hash, cryptography, probability, murmurhash

Given a message, [MurmurHash3](https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) can produce a 32-bit hash result or a 128-bit one.

```
Message msg;
char output_v32_a[4];
char output_v32_b[4];
char output_v128[16];

MurmurHash32(msg, output_v32_a); 
MurmurHash128(msg, output_v128); 
memcpy(output_v32_b, output_v128, 4);
```

**In the pseudocode above, is there any quality difference between `output_v32_a` and `output_v32_b`?**

Comment: What do you mean by "quality"? What are you using the hash for?

Comment: Grabbing the first (or last, or middle) 32 bits of Mumur128 will not give you a better hash code (distribution, etc.) than Murmur32. It will *probably* give you approximately the same quality.